# QM Error: ERROR F041 Failed to parse the model file

Tags: c, rtos, event-driven-design

I have a QM model that has been created using QM Version 5.1.1. Now, when I attempt to open it using QM Version 5.2.5, the following error arises.

If it is not possible to open QM Modeled with older version, now how should I install an olderversions of QM modeling tool.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to install an older version through Sourcefourge official QP repository.

Link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpc/